# My particles don't interact in the right way in processing, why can this be?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, processing

I Am working on a bigger project, were the perticles need to interact when they get close to eachother. The program is quite simpel. When the  balls touch each other, or the centres are closer to each other than their combined radius, they change color. However, the balls are randomly changing color right now and I have no idea why. The objects have an Arraylist with all the objects, so they can interact and their is one big class, which funtions as a particle generator.

```java
Box box;

void setup() {
    size(1000,1000);
    box = new Box(20);
}

void draw() {
    background(255);
    box.run();
}
```

the object

```java
class Object {
    int on;
    PVector loc = new PVector(500,500);
    boolean detect = false;
    PVector v;
    ArrayList<Object> others = new ArrayList<Object>();

    Object(int nin) {
        this.on = nin;
        this.loc = this.loc.add(PVector.random2D().mult(100));
        this.v = PVector.random2D();
    }

    void move() {
        loc.add(PVector.random2D().limit(5));
    }

    void detect() {
        for(int i = 0; i<others.size(); i++) {

          if(i != on) {
              Object o = others.get(i);
              float distance = sqrt(sq(o.loc.x-this.loc.x)+sq(o.loc.y - this.loc.y));
              if(distance < 100) {
                  detect = true;
              }
              else {
                detect = false;
              }
            }
        }
    }

    void display() {
        if(detect == false) {
            noFill();
        }
        if(detect == true) {
            fill(200);
        }
        stroke(50);
        ellipse(loc.x,loc.y, 50,50);
        fill(0);
        text(on, loc.x, loc.y);
    }
}
```

the generator

```java
class Box {
    int n;
    ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

    Box(int nin) {
        this.n = nin;
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            objects.add(new Object(i));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i< objects.size();i++) {
            Object x =  objects.get(i);
            x.others = this.objects;
        }
    }

    void run() {
        for(Object i : objects) {
            i.move();
            i.detect();
            i.display();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the sanity of _anyone_ ever looking at your code - please don't call a class `Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the loop in the method `detect` int class `Object`:

> ```java
> for(int i = 0; i<others.size(); i++) {
>     if(i != on) {
>         Object o = others.get(i);
>         float distance = sqrt(sq(o.loc.x-this.loc.x)+sq(o.loc.y - this.loc.y));
>         if(distance < 100) {
>             detect = true;
>         }
>         else {
>             detect = false;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

The variable `detect` is set in every iteration of the loop. Thus the after the loop has terminated, the state of `detect` depends on the last element in the list `others`. The result is exactly the same, as you would just evaluate the last element of the list.

Break the loop, if the value of `detect` becomes true. e.g.:

```java
class Object {
    // [...]

    void detect() {
        detect = false;     
        for(int i = 0; i < others.size() && !detect; i++) {
            if(i != on) {
                Object o = others.get(i);
                float distance = sqrt(sq(o.loc.x-this.loc.x)+sq(o.loc.y - this.loc.y));
                detect = distance < 50;
            }
        }
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Note, the 3rd and 4th parameter of the [`ellipse()`](https://processing.org/reference/ellipse_.html) are the width and the height of the ellipse, thus the the minimum distance  is 50, rather than 100.

[image]

Comment: what does the detect = distance < 50; do? I haven't seen that syntax before.

Comment: @Marijn the type of `detect` is `boolean`and the result of `distance < 50` is a boolean, too.

Comment: Thank you!
I should have seen the solution myself.